# Angular app not working in IE 9 on remote server

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have a simple angular application that works just fine when deployed on my local JBoss instance, but when I deploy the same war file in our sandboxed environment (also JBoss) the application doesn't load. Just shows up as a blank page. When viewed on Chrome or FF it works fine as well.

Not a lot to go on, but any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful.

Edit: Just another piece of info, it doesn't work locally on IE either when the address contains the computer name and not localhost. So `http://localhost:8080/angularapp` works but `http://[machinename]:8080/angularapp` does not.

Comment: You're definitely going to have to provide more context if you want any help. Have you tried checking the jboss logs? or the browser console? Have you tried viewing the source (to see if the html/css/js is there and just not loading) vs getting a 404 or 500 or something? This may not even be a client-side issue.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps this is not an angular issue, but a jboss configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the post you don't make completely clear in what environments you've the problem (it's clear it doesn't work using IE, but does it work in all cases with Chrome and FF?).

But the problem you're experiencing when trying to access using the machine name (`http://machinename:8080/...`), may be caused because you've not defined properly the IP bindings in the JBoss startup: by default JBoss binds only to localhost (127.0.0.1), if you want JBoss to be accessed from any other network interface, you've to define it. That can be done using the -b parameter of the startup script (run.sh for Jboss 3.x/4.x/5.x/6.x or standalone.sh if it's JBoss 7). For example:

`./run.sh -b xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your server IP) will make the JBoss accessible only from that IP (and its corresponding machine name, provided is correctly defined in the DNS or /etc/hosts ...), but not from localhost.

`./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0` will make the JBoss accessible from all the networks interfaces of your server.